# Weird Behavior in ReactPlayer

Tags: reactjs, react-player

I am trying to include videos in my react project for that I am using [ReactPlayer](https://github.com/cookpete/react-player) by cookpete.

Now the problem is it doesn't correctly parses or make us of, whatever, the url of the video inside the browser's html `video` tag where in the `src` attribute I can see `src(unknown)` is written. The weird thing is it once in a while behaves normally as it is expected to do. When I change the `src` attribute's value to the video's [URL](https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer_hd.mp4) manually by `inspecting` the browsers html it starts getting played and I can do normal stuff with it. Here is the code which I have written.

```
<ReactPlayer
            playing={isPlaying}
            url="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer_hd.mp4"
            width="100vw - 69vw"
            height="100vh - 65vh"
          />
```

The `isPlaying` stuff is a boolean which is being mantained inside `React.useState()` with intial value set to `false`.

Comment: Is working fine for me. weird. 

Check if you can find anything here: https://github.com/cookpete/react-player/issues/1165

Comment: I can't find I can't find anything similar here.

Comment: Those width and height values don't seem to be valid.

Comment: @jme11 Nope they are perfectly fine

Comment: @IshtiaqNaqi I still don't understand the width and height values you're supplying.  Can you point to something to explain them?

Comment: @jme11 I wanted the mini player to take 31% of the total width of the screen viewing my app and the same about height 35% of the screen height, therefore I used the metrics to achieve my goal, they are working perfectly fine for me. Is there any problem using them?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is a [bug](https://github.com/cookpete/react-player/issues/1508) with `React.StrictMode`. A url with `.mp4` extension isn't reloaded on the second reload induced by StrictMode.

Comment: It did behaved the same way for videos with other extensions.